# Trying to access and manipulate a HTML Collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, getelementsbytagname, htmlcollection

## Hello everybody,

I am trying to access and manipulate a HTML collection using these methods https://attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-htmlcollection . 
However, I am having an issue where I can only access it through dev tools console and not via normal JS. 
  On the screenshot lines 6 and 7 I am logging the HTML collection and its length, and the result is 0. 
 But when I do the same in dev tools console I get 7. My script is also deferred. 
 Any help would be really appreciated, thank you! [image]

Comment: Please do not post code as images.

Answer (score 1):

You likely execute the script before the elements exist.

Try

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll("article").length);
})
```